# iPhone video app that lets you switch from front to back (in) camera mid recording?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, video, camera, video-editing

Does anyone know of any iPhone (6) camera apps that lets you flip from the front camera to back camera whilst recording a video please?

The standard camera does not, and I can't seem to find any apps that do! I don't mind paying for the app

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called MoviePro. It has lots of video options. It allows you to switch between front and back cameras.

Find the app here : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moviepro-video-recorder-limitless/id547101144?mt=8